# Lookup value on insert in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

When inserting data into a table I need to be able to populate the table with data from another table based on an entry in the new record.

For example I have a table called latitude that isn't populated when a new record is created.

Latitude details are stored in a table called area which has a column called 'areaid' and one called 'latitude'.

I need the latitude field in the area table to be updated with the correct latitude based on the areaid inserted in the new record.

I am sorry if this is confusing, any questions please getin touch.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I assume here that `areaid` is a unique or primary key in the `area` table.

You can use either `REPLACE INTO` or `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. If you are going to keep the latitude in the `latitude` table as well then you could use a trigger to ensure that the `area` table is updated when you insert into the `latitude` table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER example BEFORE INSERT ON latitude
  FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    REPLACE INTO area (areaid, latitude) VALUES (NEW.areaid, NEW.latitude);
  END;
```

Comment: @Haribo83 Actually I didn't read the documentation for `REPLACE INTO` well enough, you should try to use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` instead, as it's more efficient.